# Adding attributes to Log4j 2 Events

Tags: java, logstash, log4j2

I'd like to add some additional information/attributes like "application" name to my **log4j2 Events** (for some reason this attribute is not availible in log4j2 anymore..)
The Logs are sent over LAN to a Logstash instance.

I've worked out a solution including:

1. Custom Appender Layout (https://github.com/majikthys/log4j2-logstash-jsonevent-layout): the layout extracts all attributes from the Log4jLogEvent and the additional attributes that can be provided through the log4j2 configuration and produces a JSON String.
2. Logstash configuration:

```
    input {
        tcp {
            codec => json_lines { charset => "UTF-8" }
            port => 4560
            type => "log4j2-json"
            mode => "server"    
        }  
    }
    ...
```

The solution above works but requires the Layout to be built and added/maintained as a jar in every application.

So the question is - are there any better solutions that I've missed out?
Ideal would be a solution that wouldn't require adding any new jars/classes and uses of 3rd party software. Something like RewriteAppender but without use of "MapMessage".

Answer (score 1):

You can use logstash over GELF with https://github.com/mp911de/logstash-gelf for your use case. Application name is more related to the client than to a central logstash server. Config looks like:

```
<Configuration>
    <Appenders>
        <Gelf name="gelf" host="udp:localhost" port="12201" originHost="%host{fqdn}">
            <Field name="timestamp" pattern="%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS}" />
            <Field name="level" pattern="%level" />
            <Field name="simpleClassName" pattern="%C{1}" />

            <Field name="applicationName" literal="MyApplicationName" />

            <!-- This is a field using MDC -->
            <Field name="mdcField2" mdc="mdcField2" /> 
            <DynamicMdcFields regex="mdc.*" />
        </Gelf>
    </Appenders>
    ...
</Configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a log4j 2 TcpSocketServer to receive remote logs and then forward them locally to logstash over a tcp socket (you could use a file too...).

http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/net/server/TcpSocketServer.html

I don't think this solution is ideal, but it doesn't require the custom appender.

Comment: As I've said - I need to add some infos like Application Name to know which application has sent the log. So it would be too late to modify the log on the other side with TcpSocketServer, Grok or whatever..

Comment: I created a custom layout plugin, similar to what the OP mentioned - https://github.com/savantly-net/log4j2-extended-jsonlayout